# GAS (gnu assembler) and conditional execution

Tags: assembly, gcc, stm32, compiler-directives

Stupid question.   I am writing code in pure assembly for STM32 variants.  I want to make two different versions from the same source file by assembling twice with a simple change that is selectable by the command line.
Example:   the fast version sets the uart baud rate to 1.5 Mbaud, the slow version sets the uart baud rate to 115.2 kbaud.  I can have both lines in the source, with conditional assembly directives wrapping around, sorta like:

```
.if zap=fast then assemble
   ldr   r0,=<fast baud rate>
.else assemble
   ldr   r0,=<slow baud rate>
.endif
```

and then run the assembler twice in my make batch file, like so:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -c -mcpu-cortex-m4 -mthumb -Wall  source.s  -zap=fast -o fast.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -c -mcpu-cortex-m4 -mthumb -Wall  source.s  -zap=slow -o slow.o
```

and so on with sub-files, and run the linker twice for two images.

There must be a way to do this, but I can't find it in the manual.  Any help?
Thanks in advance.   Jeff Casey

Comment: Use `--defsym` (numeric) or switch to preprocessed assembly (`.S`) and then use `-D` and `#if` as usual.